# How to create external folder in a loop in R?

Tags: r

Ok, actually I have a loop of 50 iterations and then I need an output file for each of these iterations. That happens is that with my current code I only obtain the output file corresponding to the last iteration, so could you give me a code to let me get all the files in mi current folder??. Thank you [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B1mwa.png)

part[] is a vector of length 50 (really a list but it does not matter

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your question is not a good one and is likely to bring in some downvotes if not edited: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: `write.table(part[[i]], paste0(i, ".txt")` Or maybe `sprintf("%02d.txt", i)` instead of `paste0`.

Comment: This actually works!!. I´m a rookie in regards to R. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
for(i in 1:(length(vec)-1)){
write.table(part[[i]],paste(i,"txt",sep = "."))
}
```

Comment: Ideally, explain your answer a bit to make it better.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/21420878)

Comment: @Rui Barradas Why does this not answer the question? If you check the shared screenshot, I have just modified his existing code.

Answer (score 0):

How about using `list.files()`

That lists all the files in the current directory. or you can specify a directory as the first element of the function.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, the OP wants to *write* files, not to know the files that *already exist* in the directory.